# Java JTable rowsorter between two values

Tags: java, regex, jtable, rowfilter, rowsorter

I'm trying to do "live search" between two values in JTable. Let's say this is my table:

[image: table]

I've done normal search with something like this

```
    jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String search = jTextField1.getText();

            if (search.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);                    
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + search));
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String search = jTextField1.getText();

            if (search.trim().length() == 0) {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + search));
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
        }
    }); `
```

What i want now is to do something like this but as you can see with two values 'from-to' and display only this records with are between min, max and equal to them. Let's say from 150-300. But i have no idea how to do this, i've tried combine 2 filters like

```
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
filters.add( RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, Float.parseFloat(min)) );
filters.add( RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, Float.parseFloat(max)) );
RowFilter<Object, Object> rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
rowSorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

but this is not working. Is anyone have idea how to do this? I'm starting to give up... aha my data in table are Objects and I'm using default table model. As you can see I'm just started learning java and sorry for my bad english :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
filters.add( RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, Float.parseFloat(min)) );
filters.add( RowFilter.numberFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, Float.parseFloat(max)) );
```

When creating the `RowFilter.numberFilter(...)` you need to specify which column in the table you want to do your comparison on. The default is all columns if you don't specify an index.

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but i think its wrong constructed filter anyway.

Comment: @Sniego, Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem using the information that you know so we don't have to guess what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: That is the point, i have nothing except this search function. This rowfilter is only my prediction how to resolve my issue. But actualy i just have no clue how to do sorter based on min-max value. If you really want i can post code of this application but there is only search function and table.